# Как обратится к элементу, который находится в динамическом словаре Python

Tags: python, словарь

Работаю с словарём, который в себе имеет ещё очень много словарей. Мне нужно обратится к одному из элементов, который находится, скажем так, внутри других словарей. Вот его малая часть:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "start": 0,
  "pagesize": "100",
  "total_count": 7084,
  "listinginfo": {
      "3307294723760205578": {
          "listingid": "3307294723760205578",
          "price": 0,
          "fee": 0,
          "publisher_fee_app": 730,
          "publisher_fee_percent": "0.100000001490116119",
          "currencyid": 2006,
          "asset": {
            "currency": 0,
            "appid": 730,
            "contextid": "2",
            "id": "20015271739",
            "amount": "0",
          }
        },
      "3306168823851241677": {
            "listingid": "3306168823851241677",
            "price": 177,
            "fee": 25,
            "publisher_fee_app": 730,
            "publisher_fee_percent": "0.100000001490116119",
            "currencyid": 2017,
            "steam_fee": 8,
            "publisher_fee": 17,
            "converted_price": 23,
            "converted_fee": 3,
            "converted_currencyid": 2001,
            "converted_steam_fee": 1,
            "converted_publisher_fee": 2,
            "converted_price_per_unit": 23,
            "converted_fee_per_unit": 3,
            "converted_steam_fee_per_unit": 1,
            "converted_publisher_fee_per_unit": 2,
            "asset": {
              "currency": 0,
              "appid": 730,
              "contextid": "2",
              "id": "19841538651",
              "amount": "1",
  }
},
}
```

Мне нужно обратится к елементам **"listingid"** и **"id"**, по соответствующим путям **['listinginfo']['3307294723760205578']['listingid']** и **['listinginfo']['3307294723760205578']['listingid']['asset']['id']**. Проблема в том, что поле **'3307294723760205578'** является динамическим и каждый раз изменяется. Можно ли как-то "перепрыгнуть" его и обращаться дальше? Что-то типо **['listinginfo'][key]['listingid']**. Сейчас перебираю элементы в цикле таким образом (где steam_skin является тем самым словарём):

```
for m in steam_skin:
    for a in steam_skin:
        for key in steam_keys[1:]:
            m = steam_skin['listinginfo'][key]['listingid']
            a = steam_skin['listinginfo'][key]['listingid']['asset']['id']
```

Этот код работает с ошибкой:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "steam.py", line 153, in <module>
a = steam_skin['listinginfo'][key]['listingid']['asset']['id']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

При чём верхняя строка,где я получаю **'m'** - работает. По словарю видно, что все элементы, к которым я обращаюсь являются строками. Ещё одно важное условие: мне нужно одновременно получить те самые **'m'** и **'a'** и использовать их одновременно далее в коде для формирования url'а, который тоже будет динамическим.

Вопрос в том, как решить данную ошибку и будет ли вообще работать код так, как мне нужно. Я имею ввиду, что не будет ли такого, что когда внутренний цикл пройдет переменная **'a'** изменится, а **'m'** останется прежним? Спасибо за помощь, надеюсь найдётся решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к `steam_skin['listinginfo'][key]['listingid']` как к словарю, но у него нет ключей, это просто поле.

Поэтому замените

`a = steam_skin['listinginfo'][key]['listingid']['asset']['id']`

На

`a = steam_skin['listinginfo'][key]['asset']['id']`

```py
for m in steam_skin:
    for a in steam_skin:
        for key in steam_keys[1:]:
            m = steam_skin['listinginfo'][key]['listingid']
            #a = steam_skin['listinginfo'][key]['listingid']['asset']['id']
            a = steam_skin['listinginfo'][key]['asset']['id']
```

Comment: Проблема не в этом, я и так получаю элементы с помощью steam_keys = list(steam_skin['listinginfo']). Вопрос в том, можно ли как-то "перепрыгнуть" через елемент, из-за чего возникает ошибка, и будет ли вообще этот код работать (и переменная m и переменная a должны принимать участие в формировании 1 ссылки)

Comment: @IIIyTH1K переписал

Comment: да увидел, спасибо большое. Не знаю, как я не заметил что не к тому обращаюсь)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/), который умеет искать вложенные ключи и значения любой глубины:

```
import dpath.util as dpu  # pip install dpath

In [392]: dpu.search(data, '/**/asset/id')
Out[392]: 
{'listinginfo': {'3307294723760205578': {'asset': {'id': '20015271739'}},
  '3306168823851241677': {'asset': {'id': '19841538651'}}}}

In [393]: dpu.values(data, '/**/asset/id')
Out[393]: ['20015271739', '19841538651']
```

Comment: уже решил проблему, но спасибо, думаю когда-то пригодится)